# Java - Declare Class Once Use Anywhere

Tags: java, class, static, global

Very simple problem but im not understanding static correctly.

I have java file which holds my main and its call testMain.

With my testMain it makes many classes with use other classes.

E.g. testMain>>GUI   and testMain>>model   and testMain>>controller

Now i have a class called generatorTester which i would like to declare once like:

```
public static utils.generatorTester randomGen = new utils.generatorTester ();
```

(utils is my custom package for my common classes)

Why does the above line not aloud me to do the following

```
classNameOfMainFunction.randomGen
```

Im i programming wrong here? Is this even possbile.

I bassicly want to make the class globably and use it any where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A public static field of a public class can be used anywhere, you just need to use the right syntax to access it.

If you declare:

```
package foo;

public class Global {
    public static Some thing;
}
```

And do

```
import foo.Global;
```

you can access the field with

```
Global.thing
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
import static foo.Global.thing;
```

and access it with

```
thing
```

Answer (score 2):

About the best you can get is this:

```
public abstract class GloballyUsed {
    public static int method() { return 4; 
    /* determined by fair
     * dice roll, guaranteed to be random */
    }
```

and:

```
GloballyUsed.method();
```

to call elsewhere.

Note per comment (I just learned this) since Java 5 you can import just a specific method name as:

```
import static {package}.GloballyUsed.method;
```

Note I added the keyword `abstract`, this is to further convince you that you never actually instantiate `GloballyUsed`.  It has no instances.  You probably have some reading to do on what `static` means.

Comment: So that means in all my other classes i wont need to make new GlballyUsed class?

Comment: *You can't import so specifically in Java as to just call `method()`*. You can since Java 5 using [`import static`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) but only for `static` field/methods.